# "I cannot account for my (be) so talkative. It's just my character"

Tags: sentence-construction, present-participles, linking-verbs

> I cannot account for my (be) so talkative. It's just my character.

What form of verb "be" should be used in this sentence? I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

The correct form is the gerund, **being**.  We "account for" a *noun phrase*, and the gerund is how you make a noun form out of a verb.

For example,

> [I cannot account for my being misled](https://books.google.com/books?id=YKY1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22account%20for%20my%20being%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAy_rJu4DvAhXEnuAKHUpZCsEQ6AEwAXoECAQQAg)

> [In view of these facts I deem it my duty to ... account for my being out of the ship](https://books.google.com/books?id=rH0fAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA31-PA2&dq=%22account%20for%20my%20being%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieoa-uvIDvAhVGmuAKHRqCCsUQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg)

Or any other verb:

> [That will account for my doing all the talking](https://books.google.com/books?id=lPEOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA279&dq=%22account%20for%20my%20doing%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizwMnTvIDvAhURTt8KHeC9An0Q6AEwBXoECAMQAg)

> [That may account for my saying what I did](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cjn36YgafXIC&pg=PA133&dq=%22account%20for%20my%20saying%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQoeuZvYDvAhX5EVkFHZbbD-AQ6AEwBnoECAgQAg)

Comment: Simple Present Continuous *(**my being so talkative**)* can be used to apologise for both a general character trait AND a recent episode of "talkativeness", but the Perfect form *(**my having been so talkative**)* specifically carries only the second of those senses. And of course many people would use the simple pronoun rather than the possessive in such contexts *(**me** being / having been so talkative)* - which I think is only ever a stylistic choice, with no special implications for the meaning.